# How do I use the drive.file auth scope in my Gmail addon?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, gmail-addons

I'm trying to be a good Google Apps Scripter and use less permissive scopes in my app, but I can't get it to work with https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file.

I have a Gmail addon that needs to create files and folders in the user's Google Drive. Right now I have it working fine with the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive scope in the manifest so I know the code itself functions. But when I change the scope to https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file, none of the DriveApp methods work anymore and I get an error saying I need the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive scope.

In the DriveApp docs it does say it needs the "drive" scope, but wouldn't that mean no app could ever save data to a user's Drive without having full access to all their files? That sounds crazy. Or am I SOL? I still don't quite understand how the scopes work or if I need to do any other changes elsewhere to make them work.

Comment: Are you using the the Drive Service or the Advanced Drive service? What methods are you using on your script?

Comment: I'm using the Drive service. I'm using DriveApp.getFoldersByName(), DriveApp.getRootFolder(), DriveApp.createFolder(), and DriveApp.createFile().

Comment: Drive Service `DriveApp`: no ability to use reduced permissions. Advanced Service `Drive`: (nearly) full power of the Drive REST API (v2), including `drive.file` scope compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success! After going through the Drive API I figured out I had to enable the Drive API and use Drive.Files.insert().

Comment: But you need to enable the api. I guess all your users need to enable it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible as there aren't any DriveApp methods that require that scope. Ref. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app

---

From a comment by the OP

> I'm using the Drive service. I'm using DriveApp.getFoldersByName(), DriveApp.getRootFolder(), DriveApp.createFolder(), and DriveApp.createFile().

Please read the documentation carefully. The required scopes by each method are included there.

## Example

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getrootfolder

> ## getRootFolder()
>
> Gets the folder at the root of the user's Drive.
>
> ### Return
>
> Folder — the root folder of the user's Drive
>
> ### Authorization
>
> Scripts that use this method require authorization with one or more of the following scopes:
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

Comment: My question was "How do I use the drive.file auth scope in my Gmail addon?" Your answer says what I cannot do but unfortunately does not answer my question, thank you.